# Display last five rows in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, worksheet-function

I have a simple personal money tracker based on Google form for data input and spreadsheet for calculating, statistics and so.

Everything works just fine but now I need workaround to display the last five entries in sheet that contain raw data from Google form.

This is what the sheet looks like:
[image: This sheet looks like this]

What I want to do is create new spreadsheet which displays the last five entries from the sheet with data from Google form. Please help me with right formula for this.

P.S: Would be perfect display this information right in Google form that I used to enter data but as far as I know its impossible.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read this post about [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I don't understand your question. From a sheet that already have values, do you want to pass those values to another sheet? What do you mean by "raw data"?

Comment: I mean raw data for values that collects from Google form and displayed on that sheet in my example. I do all calculations in other sheets. And yes I want to make display last five entry from that sheet on another sheet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there are no gaps in the time column, you could try

```
=query(A:D,"select * offset "&count(A:A)-5)
```

[image]

Comment: It works! I had played with numbers and "&count(A:A)--12) give me exactly 5 entry as I wish. Thanks a lot!

Comment: How to get the last 5 rows into a new sheet in the same spreadsheet !

Comment: It would just be (e.g.) =query(Sheet7!A:D,"select * offset "&count(Sheet7!A:A)-5)